# Finding defected boxes puzzle

Tags: logic, puzzle

If I have say $6$ boxes of marbles such that each of the box contains $100$ marbles each of which weigh $1$ gram. Now I get a call from my marble dealer saying that there is a chance that any of the boxes (possibly every one of them) could contain defected marbles which weigh $1$ milligram more than they should.

The question is now how can I figure out how to detect the faulty boxes with one weighing measurement on my scale that I have?

I kinda see the issue if I label the boxes with $1,\dots,6$ and pick correspondingly many marbles from each of the boxes if I knew that only one of these boxes contain defected marbles I could identify it with this strategy as I would end up with $1+ \dots + 6 = 21$ grams and $n$ milligrams where $n$ corresponds to the index of the defected box, but in the case where all of the boxes could be defected the issue is that if I for example end up with $21$ grams and $6$ milligrams it could be that box number $6$ is defected or that boxes number $2$ and $3$ are defected and I'm in trouble.

The way I see this is that I need to get rid of these pesky sums that will ruin the process of detecting the defected boxes by considering indexes for the boxes such that I wont get the possibility that this happens. Is there some trick to index the boxes accordingly?

Comment: Use numbers which have unique sums.  For example, take $2^n$ marbles from each box.

Comment: This was something I was thinking of, but I didn't know how to find numbers with unique sums. What kind of an property is this? @XanderHenderson

Comment: Measure the marbles.  As you say, you'll get 127 g and $n$ mg.  Write $n$ in binary.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with binary numbers. Is there a particular reason why powers of two give these numbers with unique sums? @XanderHenderson

Comment: Yes.  Because every natural number has a unique binary representation. (In the same way that every natural number has a unique base-10 representation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method

1. Label the boxes $0$ through $5$, and take $2^n$ marbles from box $n$.
2. Weigh the marbles.  Since
   $$ \sum_{j=0}^{5} 2^j = 63$$
   marbles have been weighed, the total mass is going to be $63$ grams and $n$ milligrams.
3. The number can be uniquely written as
   $$ \sum_{j=0}^{5} 2^{b_j},$$
   where each $b_j$ is either $0$ or $1$.  In other words, the number has a unique binary representation
   $$ \bigl( b_5 b_4 b_3 b_2 b_1 b_0 \bigr)_2. $$
4. If $b_n = 1$, then Box $n$ is defective.

#### Example

Suppose that the marbles weigh $63$ grams and $47$ milligrams.  Observe that
$$ 47 = 32^1 + 16^0 + 8^1 + 4^1 + 2^1 + 1^1 = 101111_2.$$
This implies that Box 4 is fine, and that the remaining boxes are defective.

Comment: Your first summation should read:

$$\sum_{j=1}^6 2^j=126$$

since you're omitting $2^0$ from your sum.  Corresponding changes are necessary elsewhere.  Probably pedagogically cleaner to label the boxes $0$ through $5$ rather than $1$ through $6$.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, thank you.  That is what was in my head.  I just typed it out completely wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertShore Yeah, classic off by 1 error.  Fixed now.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Not quite fixed.  You're still summing $j^2$ when you should be summing $2^j$.

Comment: Arg!  Yes.  Fixed.  Thanks.  It is so frustrating when I know exactly what I am thinking but I can't get it onto the page correctly. :/